# How to download a file properly with a proper hash check?

Tags: virtualbox, download, hashing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [EXE file package repair](https://superuser.com/questions/278633/exe-file-package-repair)

I'm trying to download the Oracle VM with Enterprise Linux and database tools from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html).

It's an appliance that can be imported with VirtualBox and then run.

It requires 3 files - I've downloaded 2 files and checked the hash with an utility called FastSum. They're correct.

But I've downloaded the third file 3 times - each time the hash is different than those specified on the Oracle website.
I've used Orbit and then IDM.

I've a very bad Internet connection - to download the 1.3 GB file it took me 8 hours.

**So is there a download manager that download the file correctly (with hash check)?

Or how can I solve this ?**

Comment: Which OS? Which browser?

Comment: Windows and i've used IDM to download , not via browser...

Comment: If they're not offering a .torrent for a file this big, that's highly unreasonable of them. A similar situation for OS X users that want to download their Update Combo (>1 GB). It's basically click 'download' and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this similar (identical?) [question](https://superuser.com/questions/278633/exe-file-package-repair) and my [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/278633/exe-file-package-repair/278669#278669) to it.

Comment: i've asked for torrent file in Oracle forum , no one replied . It seems only direct downloading . Also i'm a regular user of wget , but oracle uses authentication during downloading . i tried the same url with wget , but it failed :(

Comment: Which kind of authentication? You can pass cookies with `curl` to get around authentication.

Comment: i tried using this method by a guy from otn : http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2666987  Failed

Comment: Somewhere i read , that the download manager - GetRight hash checks its files . But their website mentions nothing . Has anybody used GetRight ?

Comment: @vettipayyan, if Oracle doesn’t provide an official torrent file, then use a torrent search engine such as [isoHunt](http://isohunt.com) to find a torrent that contains the same file (search for the filename and make sure the filesize matches). Like I said in the other question, point the torrent client to your file and re-hash, then continue it to re-download the missing bits, and discard any extraneous executables (ie cracks, etc.) that may be included in the torrent.

Comment: @Synetech , ya , i've searched for it many sites- piratebay , kickass , isohunt , monova , limetorrents - no use . Since it is freely available , no one posted in torrent sites .:(

Comment: Hmmm, that’s “ironic”. Try the donkey network with a client like eMule; you can search for the file and import it in that as well.

Comment: @Synetech , i've solved it : i've gone to my college's browsing center , and downloaded the file at 1mb/s - > hash checked it and it's correct . Now i got the VM up and running .......... huuuuuge relief . Thank u for providing so many ideas :) Also i figured out GetRight has the option of hash checking .

Comment: Ah, the wonders of a T1/OC3 line (or whatever the contemporary equivalent is) at school/work. `:-)` Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem one week ago. I installed Ubuntu 11.04 with IDM, but I found after 10 hours of download that my file had an error in the MD5 checksum.

So my advise to you is to use a torrent link by using any torrent client software like [µTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9CTorrent), because the torrent download can check and repair an MD5 checksum so you can ensure that your files can be downloaded without errors.

Comment: No torrent files for that file - i've asked that in Oracle forum - no reply